# Spark sql errors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to work with spark-sql but I had the following errors :

> error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file
>   'package.class'. Could not access term annotation in package
>   org.apache.spark, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check
>   your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run
>   with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full
>   rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an
>   incompatible version of org.apache.spark. warning: Class
>   org.apache.spark.annotation.InterfaceStability not found - continuing
>   with a stub. error: missing or invalid dependency detected while
>   loading class file 'SparkSession.class'. Could not access term
>   annotation in package org.apache.spark, because it (or its
>   dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for missing or
>   conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the
>   problematic classpath.) A full rebuild may help if
>   'SparkSession.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of
>   org.apache.spark.

My configuration :

- Scala 2.11.8
- Spark-core_2.11-2.1.0
- Spark-sql_2.11-2.1.0
- Note: I use SparkSession.

Comment: Could you share how did you solve this ?

Comment: @YashSharma, I juste used sbt tool and put into build.sbt: libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" %  "provided")

Answer (score 7):

After dig into the error message, I know how to solve this kind of errors.
For example:

Error - `Symbol 'term org.apache.spark.annotation' is missing... A full rebuild may help if 'SparkSession.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark`

Open `SparkSession.class`, search "import org.apache.spark.annotation.", you will find `import org.apache.spark.annotation.{DeveloperApi, Experimental, InterfaceStability}`. It's sure that these classes is missing in classpath. You'll need to find the artifact which conclude these classes.

So open https://search.maven.org and search with `c:"DeveloperApi" AND g:"org.apache.spark"`, you will find the missing artifact is `spark-tags` as @Prakash answered.

In my situation, just add dependencies `spark-catalyst` and `spark-tags` in pom.xml works.

---

**But it's weird that why maven not auto resolve transitive dependencies here?**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I use the above depencency, only spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar is in maven dependency; While if I change version to 2.1.0 or 2.3.0, all transitive dependencies will be there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include following artifacts to avoid the dependency issues.

- spark-unsafe_2.11-2.1.1
- spark-tags_2.11-2.1.1

Comment: Seems work.  But errors change from `Symbol 'term org.apache.spark.annotation' is missing from the classpath` to `Symbol 'term org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans' is missing from the classpath`